Referring to a typeof object within the object itself
I have a need to refer to typeof an object within the object itself like this:
type Config<T extends Record<string, Config<T>> = any> = {
    name: string,
    value: number,
    children?: { [key: string]: Config<T> }
    visibilityFn?: VisibilityFn<T>
}

type VisibilityFn<T extends Record<string, Config>>= (children: T) => boolean



const config = {
    name: 'config',
    value: 1,
    children: {
        one: {
            name: 'one',
            value: 1,
            visibilityFn: (children: typeof config.children) => children.two.value > 3
        },
        two: {
            name: 'two',
            value: 2,
        },
    },
} satisfies Config

I don't want to explicitly type the shape of children via a generic type, because with more complicated structures and multiple reuses it will get old very soon. I could just not type the function, but I obviously don't want that. The last option I thought of is to define the visibility functions outside the config, but with nested structure defining it for each element is cumbersome.
Any ideas how to make it fairly brief and strictly typed?
typescript playground example

But even if you fix that, your visibilityFn is not a valid VisibilityFn because the generic is incorrect, as shown in his playground link. Please [edit] to make this a [mre] that works as advertised before dealing with the recursion, such as if you manually typed config... maybe like this version? Your goal is to give us a version of the code that will not immediately break if we fix your recursive issue.

@jcalz Right. I wanted to avoid the approach with generic Config altogether, especially defaulting to any type, but I can see the issue here. Anyway I have edited the example, hopefully it is better now

Given this, I'd say you need a helper function. Possibly something like this version, although I don't really know how you want to deal with the deeply recursive type in general, and how to actually represent what it's doing... I got this far but I think we're digressing from the question. The answer is likely that you should make a helper function to infer the callback type, instead of trying to write an illegally circular reference directly. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Your answer addressed the problem that is one nesting deep. If I want to make it two or more levels deep then it doesn't work and makes something like this possible. I don't want an infinite recursion here, but some nested inference would be helpful. If possible that is.

It makes sense that you want this, but it's out of scope for the question as asked. My other example (the "this far" link above) actually focused on the recursive stuff, and this playground link shows what happens; what is six?! and note that children is optional so you need optional chaining, or to modify the type to somehow recognize when children is required, but all of this is out of scope for the question as asked. How shall we proceed with this question about self-reference in types?

Six is a demonstration of lack of type safety in your example. It doesn't exist in the object yet I can access it freely. Self reference, in my opinion, should include recursive types. If I want the type passed to the function to be exact it should reflect the whole structure of the object I am going to pass. This doesn't do it as I demonstrated by accessing non-existent "six" in your example.

So then does this approach where it knows that you have three but not six work for you?

Indeed, thanks!

You can't generally refer to typeof x inside the definition for the value x without running afoul of TypeScript circularity warnings. Really what you need to do is give Config<T> a properly recursive generic definition so that it can actually represent the type you need automatically intend to convey, where at each level of the tree, the optional visibilityFn method's callback parameter corresponds to the type of the children property of the parent of that level.  Something like this:
type Config<T, TP = {}> = {
    name: string,
    value: number,
    children?: ConfigChildren<T>
    visibilityFn?: (children: ConfigChildren<TP>) => boolean
}

type ConfigChildren<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Config<T[K], T> }

Here TP is the parent type, which for the top level should just be the empty  type object (which is why I chose that as the default type argument for TP).  So if children is of type ConfigChildren<T>, then visibilityFn takes a parameter of type ConfigChildren<TP>.  Then ConfigChildren is just a mapped type where each property is Config<T[K], T> (since in the next level down, T becomes the parent of the T[K] property).
Now you can't use the satisfies operator directly because you can't easily name the type config it should satisfy without referring to itself. That is, you'd need to write satisfies Config<{one: any, two: { three: any} }> or something, and mostly defeats the purpose of what you're doing. If you were happy writing out that property type as a type argument then you'd have just annotated your parameter type explicitly instead of trying to write typeof config.children.
So let's abandon satisfies in favor of a generic helper function that hopefully infers that type argument for you:
const asConfig = <T,>(c: Config<T>) => c;

And now you can call it on your object literal:
const config = asConfig({
    name: 'config',
    value: 1,
    children: ({
        one: {
            name: 'one',
            value: 1,
            children: {},
            visibilityFn: (children) => (children.two.children?.three.value ?? 0) > 3
            //             ^? (parameter) children: ConfigChildren<
            //                  {  one: unknown; two: { three: unknown; };}>
        },
        two: {
            name: 'two',
            value: 2,
            children: ({
                three: {
                    name: 'three',
                    value: 3,
                    children: {}
                }
            })
        },
    }),
})
/* const config: Config<{
    one: unknown;
    two: {
        three: unknown;
    };
}, {}> */

Here the type argument T is inferred as {one: unknown; two: {three: unknown}}, and thus inside config.one.visibilityFn, the children parameter is contextually typed as ConfigChildren<T> for that T, and thus it is known that children.two.children, if it exists, has a three property. (Note the "if it exists" part is because children is defined as an optional property of config. If you need something more specific so that TypeScript knows when it does and does not appear, you'll need to do refactoring. But the details of how this recursive type should be tweaked for your use case are out of scope here.)
This works as far as it goes, but be aware that TypeScript doesn't have the ability to infer arbitrarily complicated types. It might be that at some depth of your tree you need to wrap something in another asConfig() call so that the lower levels are inferred separately from the upper ones. Or you might find yourself having to annotate type parameters you'd really rather TypeScript infer for you. That can happen, especially when generics and contextual typing have to occur simultaneously or in some specific order. There's a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#47599 to improve this sort of inference, but there will always be cases where it just can't happen.  If you run into these you'll be much better off just writing out the type you need rather than trying to force TypeScript to do things it can't do well.
Playground link to code
